# Unmanaged C# exports sharing data with external managed assembly

Tags: c#, unmanaged

Im using [RGiesecke.DllExport](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports/1.2.2.23707) Unmanaged Exports library to create a dll which is imported by MetaTrader4. Data exchange inside the assembly works fine but how do I access the variables updated by MetaTrader from another assembly?

```
using RGiesecke.DllExport;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static class UnmanagedExports
{
    static int _value = 10;
    public static int Value        
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set { _value = value; }
    }

    [DllExport("PassInt", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static void PassInt(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

When trying to access the value from separate C# application:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(UnmanagedExports.Value);             
}
```

The output is always: 10

What am I missing?

Comment: "separate C# application" is the problem.  It will have its own copy of the this assembly with its own data.  Which was never updated by Metatrader, it loaded its own copy of the DLL.  Sharing data across process boundaries requires a process interop mechanism, like a socket, named pipe, memory mapped file or WCF.  Using a registry key might be the easiest way.

Comment: Thanks Hans. Weirdly I was already aware of the issue and had a solution to the same problem on c++ side with a data segment but new way of implementation got me confused...